# Remove one index from the array in codeigniter controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
Array ( 
    [issuer_id] => in.gsvm 
    [org_id] => 00738648 
    [doc_type] => ABCDS 
    [RROLL] => 12589 
    [YEAR] => 2020 
)
```

*I want to remove org_id from array and store that data in another variable*

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`unset()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.unset.php).

```php
php > $array = Array (0 => 123, 1 => 456);
php > unset($array[0]);
php > print_r($array);
Array
(
    [1] => 456
)
```

It destroys the variable, which in this case is the array item matching the index that you want to delete.

You assign the value to a new variable before removing it.

```php
php > $array = Array (0 => 123, 1 => 456);
php > $v = $array[0];
php > unset($array[0]);
php > print_r($array);
Array
(
    [1] => 456
)
php > echo $v;
123
```

Answer (score 1):

Store the value in a variable:

```
$orgId = $array['org_id'];
```

and remove it from the array:

```
unset($array['org_id']);
```

This is just ordinary PHP which works the same in CodeIgniter.

Answer (score 0):

You can use unset(array) method of PHP programming language to remove an item.
for example

`$dataArray = ['key1'=>'data1','key2'=>'data2'];`

`unset($dataArray['key1']);`

Then pass the array to insert function.

`$this->db->insert('table_name',$dataArray);`

You can find details example on this link: https://www.techiedelight.com/remove-elements-array-php/